# Conditional ImageBackground React Native / JSX

Tags: react-native, jsx

I know I'm just having a syntax issue, but here goes.

I'm building a weather app where the background image source changes based on weather conditions.  My quotes and weather desc work, but having trouble setting the background image based on the same conditions.

```
const weatherCases = {
"clear sky": {
    title: "clear sky",
    background: "../assets/sunnyBackground.png",
    quote1: "My whole life has been sunshine. I like sunshine, in a certain way.",
}}
```

```
return ( 
    <ImageBackground source={weatherCases[weatherName].background} style={styles.forecastContainer}> 

      <View style={styles.forecastTopContainer}>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.quoteText} >{weatherCases[weatherName]["quote" + randomQuoteNumber.toString()]}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.forecastBottomContainer}>

        <View style={styles.forecastImageContainer}>
          <Text>IMAGE</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.forecastTempContainer}>
          <Text>{city}</Text>
          <Text>{temp}°</Text>
          <Text>{weatherCases[weatherName].title}</Text>
          <Text>{hum}% Humidity</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </ImageBackground>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specifically `require()` every image resource that you will use. ImageBackground `source` prop expects the result of this require

```
const sunnyBg = require("../assets/sunnyBackground.png")

...

"clear sky": {
    title: "clear sky",
    background: sunnyBg,
    quote1: "My whole life has been sunshine. I like sunshine, in a certain way.",
}}
```

Comment: Why then not do something like this.  I have almost 50 different background images with 50 different weather cases

"clear sky": {
    title: "clear sky",
    background: require("../assets/sunnyBackground.png"),
    quote1: "My whole life has been sunshine. I like sunshine, in a certain way.",
}}

Comment: Actually, this is what I did:

background: require("../assets/sunnyBackground.png"),

And that worked.  I'm going to say that your solution worked.  I just didn't use the variable part of it, but this ultimately fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

You can define a conditional variable which may be inside the json or state object and conditionally pass the source as follows.

```
<ImageBackground source={this.state.conditional?require('./assets/snack-icon.png'):null}>
```

Here is a expo [link](https://snack.expo.io/@karthik.01/cranky-bananas)

Comment: Why couldn't be:

```
    <ImageBackground source=require({weatherCases[weatherName].background} ) style={styles.forecastContainer}> 

```

I have almost 50 different background images with 50 different weather cases

Comment: The thing is require needs to be static i guess

Answer (score 0):

```
import LadyInGrass from '../../../assets/images/lady_in_grass.jpg';

<ImageBackground
      style={styles.imageStyle}
      source={imageSource ?? LadyInGrass}>
 </ImageBackground>
```